# Crystal reports parameter vanishes; how do I make it stop?

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I've created dozens of Crystal reports and modified hundreds, and today for the first time....

1. Created a parameter.
2. Added conditions on it in the record selection formula.
3. Ran the report.
4. Crystal prompted for the value and I provided it.
5. Crystal throws up the formula editor flagging the parameter as not existing.
6. Checked the field explorer, and the parameter was not there.
7. Recreated the parameter, which is still in the formula.
8. Ran the report.
9. Crystal prompted for the value and I provided it.
10. Crystal rendered the report as expected.
11. Made other unrelated changes.
12. Ran the report.
13. Crystal throws up the formula editor flagging the parameter as not existing.
14. Checked the field explorer, and the parameter was not there.

A colleague had experienced the same problem but has no solution.

Google finds a lot of pages about prompt text and values disappearing, but I haven't seen anything about the whole parameter disappearing.

Update: It isn't disappearing any more, but it also isn't working, and when I try to delete it, it does not have "delete" on the menu.

Comment: Seems like a bug.  Have you applied the latest hotfixes for your version?

Comment: Or a corruption in the file.  If I try to save the file immediately after re-creating the parameter, I get a pop-up: "An invalid argument was encountered" (but the file date does get bumped in the Windows directory).  I don't handle updates and hotfixes, but one of the team keeps up on that pretty well.  Seems like a bug to me, too, and a rare one (twice in six years of six people doing reports).